# Problem with recursive objective-c void-method

Tags: objective-c, recursion, return, void

thats my first question here and i hope someone can help me.
I´m new at the iPhone programming and want to try an easy app...
It´s an SudokuSolver which is working with an recursive Method. In JAVA this code is making no problems, but in Objective-C the code isn´t stopping when Sudoku is solved. It´s still trying to solve the Sudoku and stops later.

Anyone an idea?!

Here´s the code.

```
- (SudokuSolver *) initWithField: (int[9][9]) field {
self = [super init];
if(self) {
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
            sudokuField[i][j] = field[i][j];
            if (field[i][j]) {
                sudokuFieldStatic[i][j] = 1;
            } else {
                sudokuFieldStatic[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
return self;
}

- (void) solve {
   [self solveFieldAtRow:0 andCol:0];
}

- (void) solveFieldAtRow: (int) row andCol: (int) col {
  if (row > 8) {
    return;
  } else {
    while (sudokuField[row][col] != 0) {
        if (++col > 8) {
            col = 0;
            row++;
            if (row > 8) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int num=1; num<10; num++) {
        if ([self checkRow:row forNumber:num] && [self checkCol:col forNumber:num] && [self checkFieldAtRow:row andCol:col forNumber:num]) {
            sudokuField[row][col] = num;
            [self showFieldInConsole:0];
            if (col < 8) {
                [self solveFieldAtRow:row andCol:col+1];
            } else {
                [self solveFieldAtRow:row+1 andCol:0];
            }
        }
    }
    sudokuField[row][col] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: could you also share your declaration and initialization of `sudokuField`?

Comment: some code is not here, so as a quick check: do you get any compiler warning? If you have a problem in `checkRow` etc, e.g. always returning non-zero, then it might take some time to finish solving.

Comment: The recursion pattern isn't very clear. I'd recommend rewriting this to put a `row >= 9 || col >= 8` check at the start of the `solveFieldAtRow` method.

Comment: When i insert an NSLOG(); over the "return" its showing me at the right time, but then there are coming more recursions. I coded it in JAVA with Exceptions.

Comment: And there are no warnings. I tested the check-Methods with debug. Everything ok

Comment: What do you mean with "with Exceptions"? Do you throw an exception at the place of the `return` statement here, to stop the recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code isn't stopping when the puzzle is solved because you don't check whether the puzzle is solved after the recursive call. So even if the recursive call found a solution, the code just continues on even after finding a solution until it has tried every possibility.

Since you say you have Java code that works, I suggest you compare the logic of the Java program versus this code. You'll probably find the Java code does include such a test.

---

**Edit** From your comment above, I see that you won't find such a test in your Java code, because there you are abusing exceptions to "return" from the recursion when a solution is found. The proper way is to have each recursive call return a true value if it found a solution and false if it didn't. And then each step should check if its child call succeeded, and itself return success if so. Something like this:

```
- (BOOL) solveFieldAtRow: (int) row andCol: (int) col {
    if (row > 8) {
        // reached the end, so it must have succeeded
        return YES;
    } else {
        while (sudokuField[row][col] != 0) {
            if (++col > 8) {
                col = 0;
                row++;
                if (row > 8) {
                    // reached the end, so it must have succeeded
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int num=1; num<10; num++) {
            if ([self checkRow:row forNumber:num] && [self checkCol:col forNumber:num] && [self checkFieldAtRow:row andCol:col forNumber:num]) {
                sudokuField[row][col] = num;
                [self showFieldInConsole:0];
                BOOL result;
                if (col < 8) {
                    result = [self solveFieldAtRow:row andCol:col+1];
                } else {
                    result = [self solveFieldAtRow:row+1 andCol:0];
                }
                if (result) {
                    // Our child call succeeded, so we pass that back up
                    // the stack.
                    return YES;
                }
            }
        }
        sudokuField[row][col] = 0;
        // If we get here, we could not find a solution. Return failure
        // back up the stack.
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought that "if(row > 8) return" would do the job.

Comment: That returns from the final recursive call when it finds that it reached the end. But the penultimate recursive call doesn't check whether that final recursive call succeeded or failed in finding a solution, so it effectively assumes it failed and goes on to try the next number.

Comment: I edited my answer in light of your comment above that you coded the Java version "using exceptions".

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot. Now i see. So i cant use my JAVA migrated code here.

Comment: You *could*, if you really wanted to. Look into `@try` and `@catch`, and `NSException`. But exceptions are called "exceptions" because they should be an exceptional condition, not the expected result of the calculation.

Comment: Don't use @try/@catch/NSException.  Not even for this.